# Postfix + procmail - delivery fails because "can't create user output file" - on CentOS 6.2

Tags: linux, centos, postfix, spamassassin, procmail

I verified that my postfix installation / relaying setup worked. Now I am having trouble with procmail. I have it wired to postfix with the following command:

```
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail -f -a "$USER"
```

I have nothing in my procmail config but the following:

```
LOGFILE=/var/procmailrc/log
```

And I send an email to a recipient that previously worked (before I attached procmail). Now it fails with error:

```
Apr  6 14:07:05 localhost postfix/qmgr[15194]: D0C3DFF6E1: from=<double-bounce@spamkill0.XXXXX>, size=938, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr  6 14:07:05 localhost postfix/local[1953]: D0C3DFF6E1: to=<root@spamkill0.XXXXX>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=local, delay=0.05, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0.02, dsn=5.2.0, status=bounced (can't create user output file. Command output: procmail: Couldn't create "/var/spool/mail/nobody" procmail: Couldn't read "//root" )
Apr  6 14:07:05 localhost postfix/bounce[1955]: warning: D0C3DFF6E1: undeliverable postmaster notification discarded
Apr  6 14:07:05 localhost postfix/qmgr[15194]: D0C3DFF6E1: removed
```

It seems like there is some sort of permissions issue but I do not know what the problem is, nor do I understand how I would go about diagnosing it further. The logfile that I specified is empty, by the way.

How can I make procmail+postfix work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i just get into the same and find the answer

```
$ sudo chmod g+s /usr/bin/procmail
```

The answer was in
http://www.irbs.net/internet/postfix/0202/1677.html

Comment: Please summarize the link, it might go away any time.

Answer (score 1):

Quite likely the user does not have permission to write to `/var/procmailrc`.

If you really insist on having central logging of all deliveries, you might want to rig some sort of arrangement to run Procmail under `logger(8)` or the local equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like postfix is not passing the name to procmail, or is sending nobody (but I'd say the first is more likely). If your users are virtual, you need to set procmail up in a specific manner, if users are actual system user, procmail should be configured in a different manner.